# Singleton destructor for unit testing in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, singleton

I need to implement Singleton pattern in Python (2.7) and cover code with unit tests.

Below is the code I use:

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
             cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance
```

For unit tests to be independent, I need to implement a destructor for this class. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just delete the `instance` attribute:

```
del Singleton.instance
```

If you are subclassing this, you could make it a class method:

```
@classmethod
def clear_instance(cls):
    del cls.instance
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Won't this cause memory leaks?

Comment: @Emons: unless your tests leave other references to the instance around after teardown, no it doesn't.

Comment: sadly, if any caching/memoization happens in your code, this will indeed leak. I am battling a similar problem now in which I cant manage to truly clear my context between tests because references are not a simple structure, and I dont feel like deleting python modules recursively just to clear references..

Comment: @Danku: then you'll have to debug where you are storing another reference to this. You could use the [`gc.get_referrers()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers), but take into account that returns objects, not names in a namespace. Still, it can help to figure out what kind of object is still referring to your singleton.